# BizTalk 2016: support for ConnectionState in new SAP NCo adapter?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016, sap-dotnet-connector

We're in the progress of migrating a BizTalk 2010 BizTalk application to BizTalk 2016, dealing with multiple SAP BAPI calls. One of the main reasons we are upgrading is due to the lack of support in SAP for the classic RFC protocol (SAP support for this ended April '16). We are now using the new NCo connectortype (the SAP .NET connector).

One thing we noticed while migrating was that we can't seem to use the ConnectionState property anymore (it looks like it doesn't have any effect anymore). This property was used to be able to perform several calls in one "transaction" towards SAP. This is a major showstopper for us.

How do we do this with the new SAP NCo adapter?

Comment: What exactly was your issue? I'm having similar issues with a flow. I never used the connectionstate property on BizTalk 2010. Only a BAPICommit call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one seems a bug, ConnectionState property should still be working. [BizTalk 2016 CU5](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4230301/bapi-transactions-in-sap-using-biztalk-server-do-not-work) might solve this issue.

Comment: You are correct. BizTalk 2016 CU5 should fix the issue. We escalated the issue to Microsoft, which provided a fix for it in CU5. However, I forgot to update this question. Therefore I'm assigning your answer as the correct answer.